# using fscanf without it eating word

Tags: c, scanf

Here's what I want to do:
If I have an integer followed by a specific string I want it to not be pushed on to a stack, otherwise I want it to be pushed on the stack. The problem is, when I test the next thing after the integer with fscanf, it "eats" the next thing, and essentially ruins my code.
for example:

```
    if(fscanf(read,"%d", &d)) {
        //If next is not the string "dont", then push but dont "eat" dont!
        push(d, write);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're in a file, you can always remember the current position with [`ftell()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell) and then go back with [`fseek()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek).

```
const long pos = ftell(read);

if(fscanf(read,"%d", &d)) {
    push(d, write);
    fseek(read, pos, SEEK_SET);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ungetc()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int ungetc(int c, FILE *stream);
```

This will allow you to put back **one** `char`

```
char ch;
fscanf(read,"%d%c", &d, &ch);
if (WantToPutChBack(ch)) {
  ungetc(ch, read);
}
```

You can only put back one `char` before "getting" again, hope this is enough.

Comment: but this would only unget a single character. Say I wanted to unget the last string or int of variable length?

Comment: @Alex Kornhauser As I said "hope this is enough.  If you need more and not use Zeta's idea, you need to save the extra `char` yourself and use those first before continuing with `fscanf(read...`.

Comment: @Alex Kornhause Maybe another approach:  Read a line of file into a buffer and `sscanf(buffer)` many times until you find what you want.

Comment: wish there was a "unscanf"

Comment: @Alex Kornhauser  If your file is text and your data is line oriented, use `fgets()/sscanf()` idiom.  Else go with the `ftell()/fseek()` model as suggest by @zeta.